# Logging in Spring-integration, statistics for the queue

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Working with Spring-integration, I am using this code for logging (and I have configured the log4j).

```
  <int:message-history/>
  <int:logging-channel-adapter id="logger"  auto-startup="true" log-full-message="true"  level="INFO" logger-name="logger"/>


  <int:channel id="messages" >
    <int:queue />
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="logger" />
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>
```

Here I am logging the full-message, but I would like to use the SpEL in order to log the ChannelName, and the message.
I need also to log the number of Messages in the Queue at each insertion or Poll but I didn't found how to do it and what to declare in the log4j.xml.

Comment: Can you please delete your additional answers [1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23056546/953327) and [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22957141/953327) and instead edit your question to contain the additional details?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing to do for log4j: you just should configure specific `category` and `level` on the matter.

`WireTap` doesn't do anything with channel for which it is configured. It just sends a message to the provided channel. And it does it only `onSend`. It doesn't do anything `onReceive`.

To get deal with `channel` you have to implement your own `ChannelInterceptor` and do logging just there. I mean you don't need `<wire-tap>` and `<logging-channel-adapter>` anymore.

To get a `number of Messages in the Queue` you should configure:

```
<context:mbean-export />

<context:mbean-server />
```

After that all Integration components will be wrapped with `*Metrics` proxy.

For example the `QueueChannel` becomes `QueueChannelMetrics`.

And this info you can get from your new `ChannelInterceptor` before logging it together with the `Message` and `channelName`.